# Refresh token with restsharp

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, restsharp

In my Console App I want to refresh a token because token experis after an hour, I am triyng to implement [Refreshing a Token](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) section, my code like:

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
 request.AddParameter("refresh_token", [My_Token]);
 request.AddParameter("client_id", [My_ClientId]);
 request.AddParameter("client_secret", [My_ClientSecret]);
 request.AddParameter("scope", "offline_access");
 request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 var content2 = response.Content;
```

but I'm getting the response:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'refresh_token'.\r\nTrace ID: 56e56b4a-92b3-445a-9fcf-972b7a481300\r\nCorrelation ID: 5cb2b84b-f128-4d4f-888c-6c9a3be1d70b\r\nTimestamp: 2019-05-16 13:01:57Z","error_codes":[900144],"timestamp":"2019-05-16 13:01:57Z","trace_id":"56e56b4a-92b3-445a-9fcf-972b7a481300","correlation_id":"5cb2b84b-f128-4d4f-888c-6c9a3be1d70b"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestSharp is serializing body in JSON or XML by default. You need `GetOrPost` to fix that https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#getorpost

```
 request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
 request.AddParameter("refresh_token", [My_Token], ParameterType.GetOrPost);
 request.AddParameter("client_id", [My_ClientId], ParameterType.GetOrPost);
 request.AddParameter("client_secret", [My_ClientSecret], ParameterType.GetOrPost);
 request.AddParameter("scope", "offline_access", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
 request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Comment: Thank you for replay, I'm still getting the same error message :\

Answer (score 1):

Changing `request.AddParameter` to `request.AddQueryParameter` did the job.

Here is the code to get the refresh token

```html
var client = new RestClient(BaseUri);
var request = new RestRequest();

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.AddQueryParameter("refresh_token", refresh_token);
request.AddQueryParameter("client_secret", client_secret);
request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
request.AddQueryParameter("scope", "offline_access");
request.AddQueryParameter("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);

var response = client.ExecutePost(request);
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response.Content!);
```

Answer (score 0):

as @SergeyKovalev points out, You need to add Parameter types to your Parameters.

```
 request.AddParameter("refresh_token", [My_Token], ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Additionally, you shouldn't be using form encoding for your content type, try json

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: @Codey did that fix your problem?

Comment: @johny No :.../